# Display results for multiple queries on new Google Maps: possible; how?

Tags: google-maps

With the [new](http://maps.google.com/maps/about/explore/) ([May-2013](http://google-latlong.blogspot.ru/2013/05/meet-new-google-maps-map-for-every.html)) version of Google Maps, is it possible to display results for several search queries on the same map--similar to how it worked in "classic" Google Maps?

See the green marks for McDonald's and red for Burger King:

[image: This is how it looked at classic Google Maps]

Answer (score 2):

Not the same colour scheme but this query worked for me:

```
Burger King or McDonald's near San Francisco, California, United States
```

[image: WA53348 example]